# How can get string after "#" from url using php?

Tags: php, url

How can we fetch the full URL with the # symbol using PHP?

or how can only fetch the text after "#" from URL using PHP?

Suppose, we get the below link

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#test
```

then we need the fetch "test" from URL.

Comment: What all have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried with $_SERVER global variable but I got all the information except #.

Comment: If you read the duplicate link you'll see that it's not possible to get the requested URL with the fragment, as this is never sent to the server. If you _REALLY_ need it you'd have to send it with javascript _after_ the page is loaded, but I think you might consider whether you're using the wrong method or not.

Comment: A lot of Thanks for the link as well as your valuable advice.

Comment: Thanks for Quick response :)